# Kick user without killing process

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I've searching for a way to kick out an specific user but without killing it's process but Google isn't helping anymore.

I use a service remotely over network in my workplace, which sometimes work really slow. I suspect some users are using too much bandwidth (iftop shows specific IPs corresponding to users connected through SSH), so I would like to kick them out (like closing an open ssh session) but without killing other process that the user may be running at the time (they should be running it under screens).

I suspect they are clotting the network by loading GUI services through SSH (a bad practice in my opinion since there are command line options available).

So, how can I kick out an user (something similar like shutting internet down) but preserve other running process?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless they are looking at videos the bandwith needs of a GUI app (say, a file explorer) aren't that big. They could be running `rsync` or similar.

Comment: You use tcpdump to identify the traffic and iptables to block it. Alternatively look into top and renice.